# Celery as a service with Django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, djcelery

I'm trying to use Celery in my Django project. and as usual, I googled stuff, read few SOF questions regarding the same, few blogs, and of course official docs.

but its very confusing when it comes to run celery as a service in django. I didn't find any source for this.

A simple django project with one App. in this App folder there is a file `tasks.py`  where all my tasks are(for now its a single task).

**tasks.py**

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab  
from celery.decorators import periodic_task 

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute="*/45"))
def mytask():
    #some stuff to do
    ...
    # return a value
```

and these are my settings configurations

**settings.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import djcelery

djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = "amqp://user:user@localhost:5672/vhost"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

`'djcelery'` added to INSTALLED_APS

Now If I want to run Celery worker I have to use this command in screen/tmux

`python manage.py celeryd --verbosity=2 --loglevel=DEBUG -B`

or

`python manage.py celeryd --verbosity=2 --loglevel=DEBUG &`

I want to know if its possible to run it is as a service like we run nginx, uwsgi, mysql, etc. I dont want to run in daemon mode. How can I do this?

The main this I just want to do `sudo service celery restart/reload/stop/start` like

PS: As I said, I had read few SOF threads, and many of them are saying that dont use `crontab`. then what should I use? Is this a security concern?

Comment: Arguably, this belongs on superuser.  Why don't you want to run in daemon mode?

Comment: Nancy if you would like to have the option to restart/start/stop etc, have you looked at supervisor or circus (mozilla). This will allow you to run `python manage.py celeryd --verbosity=2 --loglevel=DEBUG` and still easily call restart for it. More about http://supervisord.org/ or http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/0.11.1/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading [the documentations at http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html) which provides examples on how to make this be runnable as a service (for multiple different styles of service).  Note that when you do service blah start, that is going out to init.d/blah and running that script.  Normally that does in fact run the app as a daemon (feel free to edit if there's a reason why you don't want to run in daemon mode).  Note also that if you're using init.d (e.g. on centos 6 or similar; centos 7 moved to systemd IIRC), you can also use chkconfig to configure your celery service to start on reboot etc.

Comment: Daemonizing tutorial is not actually a tutorial, but a bunch of example configs with some quite hazy explanations on their use cases. And I didn't find my use case there either.